# Can i do a general redirect to all the requests to an external website

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.Net Core MVC web application, and i want to force any request to any action method to redirect to external website? is this possible to do it once for all the requests?

Thanks

Comment: Write a middleware and register it as the first middleware (and don't call `next`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , you should use `Run` extension method on `app` in `Startup` class and `Configure` method,

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.Run(async context => 
             context.Response.Redirect(@"https://Google.com"));
        }
```

Uses the Run extension to
create a simple middleware
that always returns a response

**Note: Any middleware added
after the Run extension
will never execute.**